# jQuery Timeout change to catch click outs

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an HTML table that I am populating with information from a database table.  I have made the cells in the table editable a pon click and have added jQuery to catch when the cell is done being edited (2.5 sec after last key press), ajax then sends info to a separate php file to update the database table with the changed value.  An issue that I have found is that if the cell is clicked out of to go into another cell and a change is made before those 2.5 seconds are up, the first change is never updated to the database.

**My Question Is:** Is there any way I can change my code below to also capture if the `<td>` cell is clicked out of and sent to ajax immediately to make the change in the database table so that no changes are missed?

```
       $('td').on('input', function() {
            var _this = $(this); // preserve reference to the input field here

            if(saveTimeout) clearTimeout(saveTimeout);
            saveTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(_this)
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "updatedatabase.php",
                    data: { 
                        content: _this.text(), 
                        date: _this.siblings().first().text(),
                        prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + (_this.index() + 1) + ')').text(),
                        old: old
                    }
                })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    alert( msg );
                });

            }, 2500);
        });
```

Comment: Why not event on field blur rather than field input.  This way you can skip the whole 2.5 second timeout checks

Comment: the point of the timeout is to catch if someone does not click out to another cell after editing.  Maybe they switch to a different screen or walk away from their desk or something.  Would there be a way I could do field blur and the counter both?

Comment: You may want to remove the `2500 timeout`, then it'll just work the moment you click out as you are listening to `input` event already

Comment: without the timeout it catches every keystroke.  That is a lot of unneeded connecting to the database and transfering info.  Not only does the changed number get written into the database, math is done on that number and then written to other tables also

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different variable to hold the timer for each cell. Create an empty object named `tdTimers` and use it with the global index of the cell to store inside it the timer returned from `setTimeout`. That way, when the user leaves a cell and enter another cell, the previous cell's timer is still enabled and it will eventually fire, because it has a different index inside your object.

```
var tdTimers = {};

$('td').on('input', function() {
    var _this = $(this); // preserve reference to the input field here
    var tdGlobalIndex = _this.index('td');

    if(tdTimers[tdGlobalIndex]) clearTimeout(tdTimers[tdGlobalIndex]);
    tdTimers[tdGlobalIndex] = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(_this)
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "updatedatabase.php",
            data: { 
                content: _this.text(), 
                date: _this.siblings().first().text(),
                prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + (_this.index() + 1) + ')').text(),
                old: old
            }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            alert( msg );
        });

    }, 2500);
});
```